# Cannot connect VPS Server to MS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu, vps

I'm trying to connect to MS SQL database using my VPS server IP, and login info. But I kept getting login failed error

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'root'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'root'. (18456)")

[enter image description here][1]
Products:
Vultr VPS Server
Version: Ubuntu 18.04
I already installed SQL Server 2017
In my python program, I got this

```
server = '66.42.92.32'
username = 'root'
password = 'abc'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' +
                      f'Server={server};' +
                      'Database=KyInventory;' +
                      'UID=root;' +
                      'PWD=abc;'+
                      'Trusted_Connection=no;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Please help me!

Comment: Am I understanding right? `using my VPS server IP, and login info` ?!

Comment: Yeah i'm new this stuff I thought that what's you're supposed to do

Comment: If I got it right you are using SSH username and password to access MSSql server! the SSH user `root` and its password is for SSH; I'm not a SQL Server User, but as far as i know SQL Server has its own credentials and you need to use your SQL Server credentials (e.g. `SA` as username)

Comment: correct, that's probably where I'm wrong. I'll keep searching

Comment: look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15 to set SA (or other user password) on linux version of MS SQL

Comment: I got it. Thank u so much!!!!

Answer (score -1):

When you use IP address to connect to your server, you have to set SQL-Server port even it was default. like this:

```
server = '66.42.92.32,1433'
```

for more information look at this Microsoft link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I've already tried that, it didn't work. I think the only thing I'm stuck at right now is I can't figure out the username and password.